# How to limit number of network adapters in Virtual Box?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am setting up a virtual machine with Virtual Box and Vagrant, but receiving error messages after running the "vagrant up" command:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid NIC number 9
VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid NIC number 10
VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid NIC number 11
VBoxManage.exe: error: Invalid NIC number 12
```

and so on till "Invalid NIC number 39".

How do I lower the number of used network adapters to 8?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762049/stderr-vboxmanage-exe-error-invalid-nic-number-9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows:

Open base.rb under "C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.8.3\plugins\providers\virtualbox\driver"

Find:

```
    def max_network_adapters
      36
    end
```

Change 36 or whatever number you have, to the number you want. For example, if you want to change it to 8, the new code will be:

```
    def max_network_adapters
      8
    end
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to control this in the box's vagrant file instead? Editing drivers on the host seems like it would prevent easy sharing of boxes amongst developers...

Comment: Sorry Julian, I have no idea for that now, but I will think about it. And let you if I figure something out.